# What is the type of a continuous numeric d3.scaleLinear() scale in typescript

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am passing d3 linear scales into a function using typescript.

```
import {scaleLinear} from 'd3-scale'

const myScale = scaleLinear().domain([0,10]).range([0,1])

const myFunc = (myScale : ScaleLinear<what, where, why>) => {
//draw something
}
```

I looked at @types d3 scale [documentation](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-scale/v3/index.d.ts) and found this line

```
export interface ScaleLinear<Range, Output, Unknown = never> extends ScaleContinuousNumeric<Range, Output, Unknown> {
//...
}
```

but it really doesn't clear anything up for me.

I think I need to put some info inside the ScaleLinear brackets <> but I don't know what.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first generic in `ScaleLinear` is `Range`, and the second is `Output`.

#### Range

The `Range` generic is for the type of the range data. If the range is specified in numbers (as in `range([1, 10])`) the range is of type `number`.

If the scale range is specified in strings such as colors (as in `range(['red', 'blue'])`), then the Range type is `string`.

#### Output

The `Output` generic is for the type of data that the scale outputs. If the scale interpolates numbers (as in `range([1, 10])`), the output is a number between 1 and 10, and so output is also of type `number`.

If the scale interpolates colors (as in `range(['red', 'blue'])`), the output is a color string (such as `#9a3439`), which is of type `string`.

For most cases, you can use `ScaleLinear<number, number>` for scales that interpolate numbers and `ScaleLinear<string, string>` for scales that interpolate color strings. In those cases where they are equal, you can also use the shorthand `ScaleLinear<number>` or `ScaleLinear<string>`.